# jquery clicking one function to execute another

Tags: html, jquery, css, events

sorry a bit of a jQuery noob here, but I've got this jquery+css setup and I have some code to swap out text on click and I can't help but think the solution is simple but I'm missing it...

https://jsfiddle.net/0nqet8cz/5/

The first code swaps out visible text for hidden text on click (see Fiddle output line #3).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
$("span.really4").click($.fn.myCustomFunction= function(){
var el = $(this);
if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
el.text(el.data("text-original"));
} else {
el.data("text-original", el.text());
el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
}
```

which I use the HTML as follows:

```
<span class="really4" data-text-swap="(Hide Reference)">(Show Reference)</span>
```

The second toggles text to appear when you click visible text (Fiddle output line #4).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".text_container").addClass("hidden");
$(".text_container").click(function() 
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.hasClass("hidden")) {
$(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
} else {
$(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
}
```

which I use the html as follows:

```
<span class="text_container"><span>"Hidden Text 1"</span> Visible Text 1</span>
```

The difference being of course the visible text always remains in the latter code.

The problem however is when I embed the HTML from the first into the second (Fiddle output line #1 and #2):

```
<span class="text_container">
<span class="really4" data-text-swap="Hidden">Visible Text</span>

<span>"Hidden Text 2"</span> 

Visible Text 2

</span>
```

When I click on "Visible Text" the text switches out for "Hidden Text" AND "Hidden Text 2" appears in the span.

However when I click "Visible Text 2" it does NOT switch out "Visible text" for "Hidden Text" but only "Visible Text 2" appears.

How can I edit the code to do both ?

Comment: I am not sure how you would hide the text when it is not wrapped in another element. Text nodes are hard to work with.

Comment: I tried to get a trigger("click") working, but it seemed circular as clicking one part triggered the other at times randomly

Comment: Just to clarify, if you click anywhere in your `text_container` you would like to toggle the `hidden` class and you would like to swap the text in your `really4` span with the text from your data attribute?

Comment: yes @Terminator-Barbapapa that is correct

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to get a trigger("click") working, but it seemed circular as clicking one part triggered the other at times randomly

When you trigger the click, you have to prevent it from bubbling up.

```js
$("span.really4").click(
  ($.fn.myCustomFunction = function (e) { // pass the event
    e.stopPropagation() // stop propagation
    // ...
  })
)

$(".text_container").click(function () {
  // ...
  $this.find(".really4").click() // trigger the click
})
```

Read more: [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

---

**UPDATE**

> ... my embedded  with class really4 does not trigger the span within .text_container to execute the function which allows hidden text to appear in the span

The `.really4` element doesn't need its own event listener:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".text_container").addClass("hidden")
  $(".text_container").click(function() {
    const $this = $(this)
    const $span = $this.find(".really4")
    if ($span.text() === $span.data("text-swap")) {
      $span.text($span.data("text-original"))
      $this.addClass("hidden")
    } else {
      $span.data("text-original", $span.text())
      $span.text($span.data("text-swap"))
      $this.removeClass("hidden")
    }
  })
})
```

---

**UPDATE**

> I don't know if this is a crude way to go about it, but I would love to hear if @charles or @Terminator-Barbapapa has a more elegant way to do this.

Here is an approach to consider: 1) Create a separate function; 2) Call that function from the `.really4` and `.text-container` click handlers (instead of triggering a click).

```js
$(function() {
  $(".text_container").addClass("hidden")

  $(".really4").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    swap(this)
    $(this).parent(".text_container").toggleClass("hidden")
  })

  $(".text_container").click(function(e) {
    const $this = $(this)
    $this.find(".really4").each(swap)
    $this.toggleClass("hidden")
  })
})

// New function
function swap(element) {
  $this = $(element)
  $this.text() === $this.data("text-swap")
    ? $this.text($this.data("text-original"))
    : $this.data("text-original", $this.text()).text($this.data("text-swap"))
}
```

Comment: thank you ! so this is how I did it (see Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xwnkLsa7/) 

but now my embedded <span> with class `really4` does not trigger the span within `.text_container` to execute the function which allows hidden text to appear in the span

Comment: you know I was actually attempting to do this and could not quite combine the codes like you did !! thank you so much. @charles

Comment: This doesn't trigger text swapping on `.really4` spans that don't have a `text_container` parent.

Comment: @Terminator-Barbapapa - yes that's true ! beat me to it to comment.

I believe I found a solution I'll post the answer now

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure this is what you were looking for, but I created a vanilla JS solution with a bit of help of CSS.

Logic

- use two data properties instead of one for the swappable text: `[data-original]` and `[data-swapped]`
- use CSS to edit the `:before` of the swappable element
- toggle the `.swapped` class on click on the swappable element

**update** I missed the 'nesting' part in OPs question, added support for that in the code (plus example).

```js
// Javascript

'use-strict';

//Traverse all array elements executing passed callback function for each entry
const forEachEntryIn = function (array, callback, scope) { // using internal caching
    for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) { callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); }
};

var swappables = document.querySelectorAll('.swappable');

forEachEntryIn(swappables, function (idx,el,scope) { 
    el.onclick = function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("swapped"); }; 
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

.swappable:before         { content: attr(data-original) }
.swappable.swapped:before { content: attr(data-swapped)  }

/* eye-candy */
div>div, div>p            { padding-left: 2rem }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<p class="swappable" data-original="original text 1" data-swapped="swapped text 1"></p>
<div class="swappable swapped" data-original="original text 2" data-swapped="swapped text 2">
    <p class="swappable" data-original="original text 2.1" data-swapped="swapped text 2.1"></p>
    <div class="swappable" data-original="original text 2.2" data-swapped="swapped text 2.2">
        <p class="swappable" data-original="original text 2.1.1" data-swapped="swapped text 2.1.1"></p>
        <p class="swappable" data-original="original text 2.1.2" data-swapped="swapped text 2.1.2"></p>
        <p class="swappable" data-original="original text 2.1.3" data-swapped="swapped text 2.1.3"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="swappable" data-original="original text 3" data-swapped="swapped text 3"></p>
```

Comment: thank you @Rene van der Lende ! 

I apologize if I'm misincorporating the code, but I tried you're creative solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/kw0sL1zg/1/ (see output, #5))

and the text DOES swap when embedded in a `.text_container` span but does NOT execute the function that's contained in `.text_container` to show the hidden text  (non-swappable text) to appear

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use `stopPropagation()` to stop the `text_container` click function from firing when you click on the `really4` span. And use the `click()` function to trigger the click function on your `really4` span when you click somewhere in the `text_container` element.

Here is a fully working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".text_container").click( function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
        $(this).find(".really4").click();

    });

    $(".really4").click( function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ( $(this).text() == $(this).data('text-swap') ) {
            $(this).text($(this).data('text-original'));
        } else {
            $(this).data('text-original', $(this).text());
                $(this).text($(this).data('text-swap'));
            }
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden > span { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text_container hidden">1) <span class="really4" data-text-swap="Hidden">Visible Text</span> <span>"Hidden Text 2"</span> Visible Text 2</div>
<div class="text_container hidden">2) <span class="really4" data-text-swap="Hidden">Visible Text</span> <span>"Hidden Text 2"</span> Visible Text 2</div>
<div>3) <span class="really4" data-text-swap="Hidden">Visible Text</span></div>
<div class="text_container hidden">4) <span>"Hidden Text 1"</span> Visible Text 1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

see https://jsfiddle.net/c5n80roe/2/

**UPDATE** - the code @charles provided works if there is both a `<span>` with class `.really4` present within a `<span>` that has class `.text_container` Thank you !

see Fiddle output lines #1 and #2

I added some lines to the code you provided @charles so in the case where `.text_container` does NOT contain a `<span>` with class `really4` it can still toggle hidden text:  (Note: I did have to add css `.visible>span {}`)

```
$(function() {
  $(".text_container").addClass("hidden")
  $(".text_container").click(function() {
    const $this = $(this)
    const $span = $this.find(".really4")
    if ($span.text() === $span.data("text-swap")) {
      $span.text($span.data("text-original"))
    } else {
      $span.data("text-original", $span.text())
      $span.text($span.data("text-swap"))
    }
    if ($this.hasClass("hidden")) { //I added this so that a standalone .text_container can still toggle it's hidden text
      $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
 } else {
      $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
}
  })
})
```

see Fiddle output line #4.

I then added below this code the original script for swapping out text when a `<span>` with class `.really3` is present (I had to change the code to specify `span.really3` it did not work when I used `span.really4`) as a stand-alone, so it can still swap out text all while not being embedded in a parent `<span>` with class `.text_container`.

```
$("span.really3").click(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
    el.text(el.data("text-original"));
  } else {
    el.data("text-original", el.text());
    el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
  }
})
```

see Fiddle output line #3

I think in this way all instances work whether stand-alone or combined elements.

I don't know if this is a crude way to go about it, but I would love to hear if @charles or @Terminator-Barbapapa has a more elegant way to do this. Thank you both!

Comment: See my answer to your question. It includes a fulltime working example. Did that not work for you?

Comment: @Terminator-Barbapapa I think @sharistotle wants the class "hidden" toggled on the `.text_container` element when `.really4` is clicked. Presently, your script only toggles this class when the `.text_container` element itself is clicked.

Comment: I understand, but since `.really4` is part of `.text_container` that doesn't matter in this case. Clicking on `.really4` also means clicking on `.text_container`. Which will toggle the class for `.text_container` Only leaving the scenario where `.really4` has no parent. Which is why there is a separate `$(".really4").click()` function.